# SyncPoint and CheckPoint in WMQ

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

can you give me a great detail description on both **SyncPoint** and **CheckPoint** in MQ? What are they? How does WMQ leverage them? As Detail As possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shashi has provided links to the relevant Infocenter topics. The question is too broad for Stack Overflow's Q&A format.  You might consider reading the linked docs and reformulating a more specific question after that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the *SyncPoint* is described quite well [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fa13440_.htm) and *CheckPoint* [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fa14540_.htm)